# How to debug custom node server with brunch.io?

Tags: node.js, debugging, coffeescript, brunch

I am using brunch.io with a custom server `app.coffee`.
This is what my `brunch-config.coffee` entry looks like:

```
server:
  path: 'app.coffee'
  port: 3333
  base: '/'
```

I want to use node's default debugger, but when I type `debugger` anywhere in my `app.coffee`, script execution doesn't stop. My `debugger` statement is simply ignored.

How can I make brunch run my server so that `debugger` statements are not ignored but pause script execution?

Brunch version: 1.7.18
Coffee version: 1.7.1
Node version: 0.10.30

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the debugger, it would be best to run `brunch watch` and your node app in separate terminal instances.

Just run `brunch watch` without the `-s`/`--server` option, and then separately run something like:

`coffee --nodejs --debug app.coffee`

Comment: Thanks! This works, but in addition I have to run a 3rd process in order to do actual debugging `node debug localhost:5858`